# Windows 7 install issue with Gigabyte GA-8I915PL-G Motherboard (Via VT6410 RAID SATA controller)

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I've been screwing with this W7 install (64bit) for FAR too long now. I boot to the Windows installer, it immediately asks for a driver disk for the controller, and search as I might, I cannot find a compatible one ANYWHERE.

Do any of you have ANY idea where I can find the appropriate drivers to allow me to install this damned operating system? Alternatively, is there a way to hack a Vista driver to let me do it? Anything? I'm at my whits end.

Thanks in advance!!!

-Sootah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raid Controller?

The only one available is for XP 64bit, might work, you might have to hack the inf file.

[Raid driver XP 64bit](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Driver/motherboard_driver_raid_via_6410_bootdisk_xp64.exe)

Comment: If the driver is not "signed" then you'd be out of luck. My understanding is that all drivers for Windows 7 need to be signed to install on Windows 7. (Possibly one reason why VIA did not release a version of this driver for Vista & Windows 7?)

Comment: Thanks irrational John, you are correct 64bit demands signed drivers. I guess the motherboard is just too old for W7. : -(